# Specifying a format inside of a class

Tags: c#, data-binding, timespan, string.format

I'm currently writing some software for a jumping-competition.

I've made a class to put my riders in and in this class theres also a variable to store the timing of the rider. I'm using a timespan for this as I also need to use milliseconds.

This is not a problem so far.
However, when I link my list with riders to a datagridview, the value of the time is being represented as 00:00:00 while I would need it to be 00:00.000

Is there a way that I can specify the outputstring either in my class or in my datagridview?

I know I could fill the datagridview manually and bypass the issue that way, but that doesn't really make sense.

So how can I tackle this problem?

Cheers,
Kenneth

```
public class RidersClass
    {
        public string firstnameRider { get; set; }
        public string lastnameRider { get; set; }
        public string nameHorse { get; set; }
        public string Stable { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan timeRound { get; set; }
        public int penalty { get; set; }        
    }

Riders = new List<RidersClass>();

private void showList()
        { 
            var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = Riders;
            grdRiders.DataSource = source;
        }
```

Comment: You could probably add a readonly property to your class to display the timespan in the format you want, but a better place for formatting is the presentation layer, so I would do it in the datagridview. However, to help you do that, we need to know the platform you are working on (is it asp.net, wpf, winforms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a wrapper class around `TimeSpan` like this

```
public class TimeSpanWrapper
{

public TimeSpan Time{get;set;}

public override string ToString()
{
return string.Format("{0}:{1}.{2}",Time.Hour,Time.Minute,Time.Second);
}   
}
```

Then replace the `TimeSpan` object in your class with the `TimeSpanWrapper`, when the binding will occur for this class the `ToString()` method will be called and return the string in the format you like.

Comment: Good idea, but your format string would not produce what the OP wants.. The correct thing to put in the `ToString` would be `return Time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ffff");`

Comment: Thank you Dimitris for your reply. This does look like a good idea, but how can I then add a Timespan to my class? Because I'm applying this class to a list. So when I add or modify the time, I have to edit the TimeSpanWrapper?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain My ToString() method was just an example of how he can achieve what he wants, I wasn't sure about the format and added a sample

Comment: Change the timeRound TimeSpan object to TimeSpanWrapper and when you need to edit the value, do it like this: timeRound.Time = new TimeSpan(); and you're ready!

Comment: The trick was to use the .Time for the timeRound. However, when I try this in my code I still get error messages:                                         Riders.Add(new RidersClass { firstnameRider = "FirstName " + i.ToString(), lastnameRider = "Last Name " + i.ToString(), nameHorse = "Horse " + i.ToString(), Stable = "Stable " + i.ToString(), timeRound.Time = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:00.000", @"m\:ss\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), penalty = (i * 4) });

Comment: Ok, I've found it. I needed to create a new instance of the TimeWrapper class: timeRound = new TimeSpanWrapper { Time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:00.000", @"m\:ss\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Thank you Dimitris for your help!

Comment: @Cainnech Glad I could help!